# Google Sheets - Custom function with UrlFetchapp.fetch working in debugger, but not when called from sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet for personal use that uses data from GoogleFinance, which offers everything BUT a company description for a ticker. My solution was to get a free API key from alpha vantage, and parse the data with a custom function.

```js
function getCompanyDesc(tck) {
  let _url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=" + tck + "&apikey=XXXXXXXXXX";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(_url);
  let obj = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  if(obj.Description && obj.Description.length > 0){
  return obj.Description;
  } else{
    return response.getContentText();
  }
}
```

When I run this in the debugger, (with my real api key and a hard-coded value for tck), the correct response is logged to the console. However, when I try to call the function in the sheet, I get this response -

[image]

Which seems to indicate that the sheet is attempting to call the api multiple times, but I don't understand why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You refreshed the spreadsheet or changed the formula more than 5 times within a minute most likely

Comment: No, I can switch between the sheet and debugger and it always works in the debugger, but never in the sheet..